# How do I transform url in js for using in facebook share button?

Tags: javascript, angular, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, share

First of all, I have dymanically generated page, its url is

```
https://example.com/main?id=First%20Theory&id2=A&id3=87710
```

When I go to [Facebook Developers Tool Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/) and generate link for share button, it generates this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmain%3Fid%3DFirst%2BTheory%26id2%3DA%26id3%3D87710&src=sdkpreparse
```

I use this link in facebook share button and it works and shares well.

Then I need to use variable for this link because my pages are generated dynamically.

So I callculate the url in js and put the link like a variable:

```
<a class="fb-share-button"
     [href]="urlToCopy"
     data-layout="button_count" data-size="small">
     <a target="_blank"
       [href]="'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + urlToCopy + ';src=sdkpreparse'"
       class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">{{urlToCopy}}</a>
</a>
```

where urlToCopy

```
https://example.com/main?id=First%20Theory&id2=A&id3=87710
```

Then when I do share with this share button, facebook modal window opens with weird url

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://example.com/main?id=First%20Theory&id2=A&id3=87710;src=sdkpreparse
```

and sharing doesnt work correct.

How can I solve this problem and what url transformation should I do with js for using it in facebook share button?

Comment: What you are doing here, is introducing one URL as the value of a query string parameter into another URL - so the first one should of course be properly URL-encoded, as URL parameter values _always_ should be. So apply [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing here, is introducing one URL as the value of a query string parameter into another URL - so the first one needs to be properly URL-encoded.

Apply [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to it.